# How to prevent duplicated http calls in same page with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 controllers which have to show same data in the view (username).

How can I prevent multiple http calls? I mean,
if user info is gotten already: save it to an object.
if user info isn't gotten and second call came: second call must wait first call's end.

If there is another way to write this code, please tell me.
I want to use this code with and without angularjs's cache method. If you suggest me use it with cache method, please tell me the alternative code without cache method.

```js
app.controller('myController1', function (getUserInfo) {
    getUserInfo.getList().then(function (userInfo) {
        vm.userInfo = userInfo;
    });
};

app.controller('myController2', function (getUserInfo) {
    getUserInfo.getList().then(function (userInfo) {
        vm.userInfo = userInfo;
    });
};               

app.factory('getUserInfo', function ($http) {
    return {
        getList: function () {
            return $http.post('http://www.foobar.com/api')
                .then(function (response) {
                    userInfo = response.data;
                    return data;
                }, function (error) {
                    return 'Some error happened';
                });
        }
    };

});
```

Note: Angularjs version is: 1.5.5 and 
Data must be refreshed when user refreshed the page. Therefore I can't use local storage or session.

Answer (score 0):

Are both controllers referencing the same `vm.userInfo` object?  If so, you can check if `vm.userInfo` already contains data or not:

```
if(vm.userInfo.length < 1) {
    getUserInfo.getList().then(); //etc....
}
```

Comment: Yes this might be a solution but I need to figure out how can I handle multiple http calls. + If http request isn't answered yet, request played twice also.

Answer (score 0):

For things that should only load once in your app you can load them in the .run section and then set the loaded value to a static service or even localStorage/sessionStorage.

```
myApp.run(['getUserInfo', function(){
    getUserInfo.getList().then(function (userInfo) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(userInfo));
    });
}]);

app.controller('myController1', function (getUserInfo) {
    vm.userInfo = sessionStorage.getItem('userInfo');
};

app.controller('myController2', function (getUserInfo) {
    vm.userInfo = sessionStorage.getItem('userInfo');
};
```

Your data is now loaded only once and you've removed unneeded HTTP calls from your app.

Comment: I can't use session or local storage for this situation actually. Because I am getting a list which can be updated. If user refresh the page, It must see new data. I am trying to ask, how can I prevent multiple http calls in the same page. Thank you.

Comment: Then use a service that accesses and provides the data across all controllers within the app.

Comment: So, the data can change frequently (ie: between page loads) and yet you don't want to load it that often?

Answer (score 0):

Just rewrite your service like this :

```
 return { 
    data:null,
    getList: function () {
        if(!data){
           var me = this;
           return $http.post('http://www.foobar.com/api')
            .then(function (response) {
                me.data = response.data;
                return data;
            }, function (error) {
                return 'Some error happened';
            });
    }else{
       var deferred = $q.defer();
       deferred.resolve(this.data);
       return deferred.promise;
    }
};
```

It will perform the request only once, if you need to refresh them, just set data to null, f5 will refresh the datas.

Comment: It says data is not defined for if(!data) and you forgot to close return's bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have two controllers in same page which is calling same function. But anyway I've tried to give a solution for your situation using $rootScope. Hopefully it will help you :)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []).run(function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.functionCalls = [];
    });

    

app.factory('getUserInfo', function ($http, $rootScope) {
    return {
        getList: function () {
          if ($rootScope.functionCalls['getList'] == 1) {
            return '';
          }
          else {
           $rootScope.functionCalls['getList'] = 1;
           return $http.post('https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos')
                .then(function (response) {
                    userInfo = response.data;
                    return data;
                }, function (error) {
                    return 'Some error happened';
                });
          }
        }
    };

});

app.controller('myController1', function ($scope, getUserInfo) {
    var userInfo = getUserInfo.getList();
      if(userInfo != '')
        $scope.userInfo = userInfo;
});

app.controller('myController2', function ($scope, getUserInfo) {
    var userInfo = getUserInfo.getList();
      if(userInfo != '')
        $scope.userInfo = userInfo;
});
```